# Some idea in designing a graph database

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan

I am new to graph database, so wanted some idea of designing a simple social things:

A User will have the following property:

`userId, name, sex, dob, about, place, country,........some other fields`

A post will have the following property:

`postId, text, date, postedBy, like, follow`

Now suppose there are user `U1, U2, U3, U4`
Posts: `P1,P2,P3,P4`

Now my question is what amount of information should i keep in graph db. Let say

- for `vertex U1` shall I keep all information (userid,name,sex,dob.....) of users with it in the graph database only.
- for `vertex P1` shall i keep all information(postId, text, date, postedBy, like, follow) with it in the graph database only.

OR

only partial information e.g

- for user vertices only `userId and name` and rest information should be in Nosql or Relation db
- for post vertices only 'postId and text` and rest information should be in Nosql or Relation db

I just wanted to know common practice in Graph DB world for this kind of scenario?

I am using Cassandra and thinking of using Titan Graph Database.?

`Next question, which one is better choice to notify all users involved in the discussion about any new comment,likes...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titan and virtually any graph database will be good at storing all the information you cited.  In most cases, the main thing you want to avoid putting in the graph, as far as a data type goes, would be large amounts of binary data, like a file/image.  Such things are best stored elsewhere, like Amazon S3, and just referenced within the graph in some way as a pointer.

As far as "notifications" go, I'm not sure I understand your question.  How you choose to "notify" a user of "something new" isn't really a function of the graph or cassandra.  If you really just mean, how do I go about recommending the newest posts to a user, then a graph database is fine for that and Titan would likely be the best choice due to its support of [vertex centric indices](http://thinkaurelius.com/2012/10/25/a-solution-to-the-supernode-problem/).  You would basically create an index that sorted your edges from user to post by descending date order and could then easily grab the first 10 newest posts.

Comment: "notifications" means same as SO.Whenever someone like,..post comment all user involved in discussion will be notified. Next thing that you are saying that instead of storing a half user info in Titan db and half in some other db(cassandra, or some othe) `its better to store all info in titan only no matter how big data its is except blob or binary data`?? right?

Comment: Ok, then I guessed correctly as to what you meant by "notifications" and my answer basically stands.  And, yes, store all of your data in Titan (at least insofar as you have described it in your question).

Comment: tell me one thing shall I treat graph db as a nosql DB with plus point of storing data and also do all graph functions? If yes then then I think i should use Titan to store my data(except binary) cos its kind of social data(likes,follow,reply..)

Comment: "social data" is inherently graph-like so it makes sense to store it as such.  If that is the primary nature of the data you seek to store, a graph should be a good match for that use case.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question in above comment :) I am confused :(

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question, as I thought I had answered it by saying affirming the use of a graph for "social data" (which you mentioned was your use case).  A graph database is a type of nosql database, so I'm not sure what you mean by "treat graph db as nosql db".  If you feel like clarifying what your asking, I can try to be more specific in that regard.

Comment: My confusion is can I use titan as I use cassandra because its support cassandra+graph functions, to store my all data(except binary)? cos I was previously thinking to store partial data in Titan and partial data in other db because my thinking was that Graph db is just for storing few data and I can't use it for storing all my data.

Comment: I think you unnecessarily over-complicate your design by adding more databases when the graph is likely all you will need.  No aspect of your use case makes it sound to me as though you can't store all of it in the graph. Keep it all in the graph, except for binary data.